# Get a PFUser details who are not current user

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-framework

I am using the Parse framework and have it set up where I can login and access the user who logs in PFUser object. I want to be able to visit a friends page and to do this i need to query and retrieve data (names and other pieces of information) of a PFUser object which is not the on that is logged in. I cannot find any queries that let me access data from the User class. I hope this makes sense,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what sort of criteria you want to search on, but you can query `PFUser`s just like you would any other `PFObject` within Parse. The only difference is that you create your query with the `+[PFUser query]` method. Here's an example from [Parse's documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-querying/iOS):

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"gender" equalTo:@"female"]; // find all the women
NSArray *girls = [query findObjects];
```

You can also query where a user is an associated object on some other class in Parse, and you can also handle results asynchronously:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:user];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  // do something with results
}];
```

Check out the [query documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS) for other examples of the sorts of things you can do with queries.

Comment: Did this solve solve your problem, Oli? If so, please accept James' answer